# Find the density of $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ for an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, transformation, exponential-distribution

We have the iid random variables $(X,Y)$ where $f_x(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, $x>0$.

We are given $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ and asked to find the cdf and the density function.

Here's my attempt.

$Z=\frac{X}{Y}$, $W=Y$.

I think this is a one-to-one transformation because we can express $X,Y$ in terms of $Z,W$ as $X=ZW$, $Y=W$.

Then,

$f_{ZW}(z,w)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{|\partial(z,w) / \partial(x,y)|_{x=zw,y=w}}$.

With:

$\frac{\partial(z,w)}{\partial(x,y)}=\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \\
     \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \\
  \end{array} \right]$

$=\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \frac{1}{y} & x \\
      0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} \right]$

Therefore,

$f_{ZW}(z,w)=\frac{f_X(x) f_Y(y)}{w} = \frac{f_X(zw)f_Y(w)}{w}$.

From there, though, I'm not quite sure how to finish.

I know that it follows:

$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{ZW}(z,w)dw$
$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f_{X}(zw)f_Y(w)dw}{w}$.

But I don't know how to get my PDF and density function from this result. Do I just use the exponential function and plug in my new variables? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$${\partial(x,y)\over\partial(z,w)}=\begin{bmatrix}w&z\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$${f_Z(z)}=\int_{0}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(y)\Big{|}{\partial(x,y)\over\partial(z,w)}\Big{|}dw=\lambda^2\int_{0}^\infty we^{-(z+1)\lambda w}dw={1\over(z+1)^2}$$

Comment: This would result in a negative $F_Z(z)$. Is that right?

Comment: Also...where did the $\lambda^2$ go???

Comment: No. $F_Z(z)=\int_0^z{1\over(t+1)^2}dt=1-{1\over1+z}$. $\lambda^2$ gets cancelled because we get $\lambda$ in the denominator while integrating $e^{-(z+1)\lambda}$.

Comment: Gotcha - worked it out myself and saw the same thing happen. Thanks a bunch.